# Adding secondary IPv6 during boot process fails

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ipv6

I am running a Debian Jessie System, stable with latest updates, and I have the problem that the second IPv6 address is not added to the interface when I boot the server.

This is my **/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 95.211.38.42
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        network 95.211.38.32
        broadcast 95.211.38.63
        gateway 95.211.38.62

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 95.211.38.106
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        network 95.211.38.96
        broadcast 95.211.38.127
        gateway 95.211.38.126


# --- IPv6 ---

iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0001:0000:0000:1337
        netmask 64
        gateway 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0000:0000:0000:0001

#       up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0001:0000:0000:4000/64
#       down /sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 del 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0001:0000:0000:4000/64
        up ip addr add 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0001:0000:0000:4000 dev eth0
        down ip addr del 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0001:0000:0000:4000 dev eth0
```

After the server is booted, the IPv6 ...:4000 is down. But when I run "up ip ..." manually, the IPv6 ...:4000 is up again.

I have also tried [following](https://serverfault.com/questions/628297/debian-up-in-etc-network-interfaces-not-working), but it doesn't work either

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0001:0000:0000:1337
        netmask 64
        gateway 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0000:0000:0000:0001

iface eth0:1 inet6 static
        address 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0001:0000:0000:4000
        netmask 64
        gateway 2001:1AF8:4100:A061:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

What can I do?

Are following log entries during the boot process useful?

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep eth0
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [    1.767095] tg3 0000:20:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM95723) rev 5784100] (PCI Express) MAC address 78:e3:b5:fc:7f:22
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [    1.767098] tg3 0000:20:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 5784 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[0])
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [    1.767100] tg3 0000:20:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[1] TSOcap[1]
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [    1.767102] tg3 0000:20:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [   10.842932] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [   13.308203] tg3 0000:20:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [   13.308214] tg3 0000:20:00.0 eth0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [   13.308236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jan 12 11:13:01 viathinksoft vmunix: [   24.203446] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to specify two gateways. Linux won't allow adding two equally-specific routes (same prefix, same metric), so `ifup` gets an error while configuring eth0:1 inet, and gives up immediately.

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

If `95.211.38.62` and `95.211.38.126` belong to the same router, adding just one of them as a "gateway" should be enough.

(If they actually are different routers, it gets more complicated. AFAIK, Linux doesn't *directly* support multi-homed systems, unless you set up policy routing via `ip rule` and multiple routing tables, one rule + one table for each source subnet.)

Also, suggestions:

- Do not specify `broadcast` or `network`, the system can calculate them from the netmask.
- Do not use `eth0:x` aliases, just add the extra addresses directly to eth0.
- `netmask` is OK, but it's shorter to say `netmask 27` or `address 95.211.38.42/27`.

The following configuration should work:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
        address 95.211.38.42/27
        gateway 95.211.38.62

iface eth0 inet static
        address 95.211.38.106/27

iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2001:1af8:4100:a061:1::1337/64
        gateway 2001:1af8:4100:a061::1

iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2001:1af8:4100:a061:1::4000/64
```

*(The [canonical form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952) of IPv6 addresses is lowercase & compressed.)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it later. But I do not think that the server gave up after eth0:1 inet, because eth0 inet6 (1337 ip) is up. I am sorry about the stupid question, but how do I find out if I need two different gateways? I used exactly the information the data center gave me. I am a bit afraid that I do something wrong - for example they were very angry when I accidently used a wrong IP due to a typo and blocked the server from their switch.

Comment: If they prefer yelling about this sort of thing after it happens, instead of preventing it early, that doesn't sound like a well-run datacenter... (Using the wrong address can cause troubles for another customer, who owns that address – but using the wrong gateway would merely break your own connection, not anybody else's.)  Anyway, one way to check would be by comparing the MAC addresses – either from `ip -4 neigh` or from `arping` (for IPv6, `ip -6 neigh` and `ndisc6`).

Comment: The 2 gateways are the same machine, they have the same MAC. Thanks for this hint.
Just for completeness, in case someone requires the information: I have pinged both Gateway IPs, and then ran `arp -a` .

Comment: Alas, the configuration didn't work. For the additional IPv4 address I had to use eth0:1 instead of eth0. This is the only change I did, based on your script, otherwise it didn't work. This modified version worked after I ran ifup and ifdown, but after reboot, the second IPv4 address is down. The second IPv6 address is down, too. :-(

Comment: Adding auto `eth0:1` solves the problem for IPv4, so both IPv4 addresses are online after boot. But the :4000 IPv6 address is still down. I don't know what to do.